# Git create new orphan branch on remote without pulling any branch

Tags: git, git-clone, git-checkout

I'd like to create a new branch `apple` on a remote. This works:

```
git clone https://example.com/.git repo --depth 1 && cd repo
git checkout --orphan apple
git push origin apple:apple
```

The problem is that it downloads the current content of the default branch in the `clone` step. This is useless for the task since I'm only creating and pushing an orphan branch. The `--depth 1` helps avoid the rest of the history, but if the current tip of the default branch is very large it still takes a lot of time.

Apart from creating an empty orphan branch on the remote that I can use in the `clone` step, any way of avoiding this?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should work without cloning at all?

```sh
git init -b apple repo && cd repo
# commit
git remote add origin https://example.com/.git
git push origin HEAD
```

Comment: `push` `HEAD` to what? I think it should be `git push origin HEAD:apple`. Even better `git push origin -u apple:apple`.

Comment: @phd: push `HEAD` to the same branch name, which works fine IIRC (I always use `git push -u origin HEAD` to set up new branches). Otherwise there’s not necessarily a point in `git init -b apple`.